# Bernoulli distribution; test p <= 0.3

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, bernoulli-distribution

I have a random variable $X \sim Ber(p)$ and I should test:

$$H_0: p \leq 0.3$$

$$H_1: p > 0.3 - alternative$$

I tried to use $\chi^2$- test, but there is a problem: the number of degrees of freedom $k = s - 1 - r = 2 - 1 - 1 = 0$, where $s = 2$ - the number of classes, $r = 1$ the size of the parameter $p \in \mathbb{R}^r = \mathbb{R}^1$.

Thus I tried to reformulate the problem in this way. Let's fix the number of experiments in the Bernoulli scheme $k = 5$ and construct the random variable $Y = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{k = 5}X_i, X_i(w) \in \
\{0,1\}$ - the number of successes, thus our new hypothesis $H_0$ is:

$$H_0: Y \sim Bin(5, p), p \leq 0.3$$

$$H_1: Y \sim Bin(5, p), p > 0.3 - alternative$$

Now the number of classes "most likely" $\geq 2$.

If I had a series of samples $Y = (Y_0, ..., Y_{15}) = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$, thus

I would have 3 classes: $0, 1, 4 \Rightarrow$ I can use $\chi^2$-test.

$\textbf{Question}$: Is this a good solution or some better methodology exist? If so, may you tell about it, or provide a direction for research?

Comment: A $\chi^2$ test does not really work for a one-tailed hypothesis test here.  You could use it for $H_0: p=0.3$ against $H_1: p \not=0.3$ with a large enough sample size, and you would have $2-1=1$ degree of freedom.   If your sample size was $k$ and you saw $y$ successes, you would be looking at $\frac{(y-0.3k)^2}{0.3k}+\frac{(k- y-0.7k)^2}{0.7k}$ possibly with a continuity correction.  $k=5$ is not really enough as $0.3k=1.5$

Comment: @Henry, $k = 5$ - it's the fixed size to test hypothesis for binomial distribution, 
$\frac{(y - 0.3k)^2}{0.3k} + \frac{(k - y - 0.7k)^2}{0.7}$ is a statistic to test $H_0: p = 0.3$ and $0.3 k = 0.3 \cdot 5 = 1.5$ is the estimation whether to used $\chi^2$ test to test $H_0: p = 0.3$

May you provide suggestions how to test $H_0: p \leq 0.3$?

Comment: You can test the simple hypothesis $H_0: \, p= 0.3$. Under $H_0$ the sum $S:= \sum_{i=1}^{15} Y_i$ is Binomial with size $15 \times 5 =75$ and  probability $p= 0.3$. WIth your alternative you should reject $H_0$ when $S$ is large. The $p$-value is $\text{Pr}\{\text{Bin}(75, 0.3) > S_{\text{obs}}\}$.

Comment: @Yves, Testing hypothesis $H_0: p \leq 3$ is the main problem, thoughts about $Bin$ distribution are my attempts to provide a test.

May you provide any other suggestions how to test $H_0: p \leq 3$?

Comment: Except for small samples (c. 10 or less), the Student t test is the standard solution.

Comment: @whuber, May you provide a link to the example?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=one+binomial+proportion+t+test

Comment: @Daniil Vorobeyv You arr right, I missed the important point in your question.